# Get the size of non-client area of a themed Edit Control

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, themes

How do you get the width of the border (non-client) of a themed Edit control in Windows XP and later versions?

On Windows 7 `GetThemeMetric` with `TMT_BORDERSIZE` as property identifier returns 0 for an existing edit control and 1 if no handle is provided. But on closer inspection it seems it should be 2.

When `WS_VSCROLL` or `WS_HSCROLL` windows styles are included for the control then the scrollbars are drawn inside that border and they are indeed 2 pixels away from the outside edge of the control, so I assume there is a way of getting the correct information.

The reason for the query is for me to be able to set the client area size when `WM_NCCALCSIZE` occurs when creating a custom control.

[image]

Comment: You shoud [edit] your question and add a picture showing which width you're talking about.

Comment: Wine uses `GetSystemMetrics()` instead, see my updated answer. Also they don't handle `WM_NCCALCSIZE` in themed edit. All this is propably for compatibility reasons. If themes were allowed to change NC size, clipping of the actual content could occur in client programs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How do you get the width of the border (non-client) of a themed Edit
>   control in Windows XP and later versions?

The following works for all controls, whether they are themed or not. It doesn't even need the theme API.

1. Call `GetClientRect()` to get the size of the client area.
2. Call `ClientToScreen()` to transform client rect to screen coordinates.
3. Call `GetWindowRect()` to get the rectangle of the control including NC area, in screen coordinates.
4. Calculate difference between client rect and window rect coordinates to get size of border (e. g. `leftBorderWidth = clientRect.left - windowRect.left`).

---

**Edit:**

Interestingly, the Wine source [theme_edit.c](https://github.com/wine-mirror/wine/blob/5485189eb0d23167de3251fd4b84de70458a9815/dlls/comctl32/theme_edit.c#L44) doesn't use `GetThemeMetric()` at all. Instead they call [`GetSystemMetrics()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724385(v=vs.85).aspx) with `SM_CXEDGE` and `SM_CYEDGE`.

On my systems (Windows 7 and Windows 10), this returns the correct value of `2`.

Comment: I'm guessing this does not work for the most evil controls of them all, the combo box. The combo box draws its own borders inside the client area!

Comment: I am accepting this answer because `GetSystemMetrics` seems to be the closest to anything usable. The wine code is quite interesting and I noticed that `TBaseVirtualTree` of VirtualTreeView uses it as well in its `WMNCPaint`. That is until someone provides a more "theme" related way of doing it.